# get distance between 2 points and figure out speed

Tags: java, android, math, gps

I would have thought this is trivial, but here at the end of the day my brain is dead.

getting distance in meters seems to work, miles seems to be broken, and speed seems to be broken.
any help would be appreciated.

```
    public static double distFromInMiles(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) 
    {
        double earthRadius = 3959;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                   Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                   Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        double dist = earthRadius * c;

        return dist;
    }

    public static double distFromInMeters(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) 
    {
        double earthRadius = 6378137;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                   Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                   Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        double dist = earthRadius * c;

        return dist;
    }

    public static double distFromInKiloMeters(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) 
    {
        double earthRadius = 6371;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                   Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
                   Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        double dist = earthRadius * c;

        return dist;
    }


    protected void checkDistanceFromPOI(LatLng latLng)
    {

        long thistime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long deltatime = lasttime - thistime;

        double hours = (double)deltatime / ((double)1000.0 * (double)60.0 * (double)60.0);

        String s;
        double distFromInMeters = LocationGPSServices.distFromInMeters(lastLocationPoint.latitude, lastLocationPoint.longitude, latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);
        double distFromInMiles = LocationGPSServices.distFromInMiles(lastLocationPoint.latitude, lastLocationPoint.longitude, latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude);
        double speed = distFromInMiles/hours;
        double speed2 = distFromInMeters/hours;

        s = "*****************distance from last point \n"
                + " lat/lng 1 = " + lastLocationPoint.toString() + "\n"
                + " lat/lng 2 = "+ latLng.toString() + "\n"
                + " in meters = " + distFromInMeters + "} \n in miles = " + distFromInMiles + " }\n "
                + " elapsed time = " + deltatime + "secs \n"
                + " speed = " + speed2 + "meters per hour \n"
                + " speed = " + speed + "miles per hour";
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Writer.appendText(s, "gps.txt", getActivity());
        lasttime = thistime;

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you use the build in Location.distanceBetween?

Comment: whoa, didn't even know it existed xD here i was being difficult about it. make it an answer and ill accept.

Comment: If you don't like Location.distanceBetween you could always use distFromInMeters() * 1609.344D.

Comment: its nor a good idea to have three functions, use the meter based, and convert to miles,or km

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use the static method

```
Location.distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)
```

Also you can use the `getSpeed ()` method in the Location class.